# Windows 2008 Standard не может подключить GPT диск, "Неизвестное устройство"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

*Windows 2008 Standard*. c рейд контроллером *RS2BL040*.

Пытаюсь подключить жесткий диск 3 ТБ. Если при инициализации выбираю *MBR* и создаю 2 диска на 2 и 1 Гб, то все работает хорошо.

Если же я пытаюсь создать диск *GPT*, то при создании тома у меня в списке устройств появляется "Неизвестное устройство" с *DriverID* `STORAGE\Volume`

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю сам на свой вопрос, как решил проблему. В windows при установке драйверов есть логи, они находятся в папке *windows/inf*. В логах я нашел ошибку по которой дравера не смогли установться. Остуствие прав на папку *windows/temp*. После исправления прав доступа, все заработало.

---

Преобразовано из комментария участника @Денис Ильиных